# ARM32, phys_to_virt, Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address

Tags: c, linux-kernel, android-source, paging

I'm working on implementing a variant of https://apenwarr.ca/log/20190216. Long story short, the main idea is to have a space in memory where to keep informations and to retrieve this information after a soft reboot/panic.

In my case, I just want to keep some variables from a reboot to another. So I've worked on a simple variant of this mechanism to do the job. The code is simply a copy paste from the original patch with some raw adaptations. I've added a syscall to enter kernel mode to execute this code (not shown here).

```c
    struct logbits {
        int magic; /* needed to verify the memory across reboots */
        int state;
        int nb_reboot;
    };
    
    #define PERSIST_SEARCH_START 0
    #ifdef CONFIG_NO_BOOTMEM
    #define PERSIST_SEARCH_END 0x5e000000
    #else
    #define PERSIST_SEARCH_END 0xfe000000
    #endif
    #define PERSIST_SEARCH_JUMP (4*1024)
    #define PERSIST_MAGIC 0xba5eba11
    
    /*
     * arm uses one memory model, mips uses another
     */
    phys_addr_t physmem_reserve(phys_addr_t size) {
    #ifdef CONFIG_NO_BOOTMEM
        phys_addr_t alloc;
        alloc = memblock_find_in_range_node(size, SMP_CACHE_BYTES,
                PERSIST_SEARCH_START, PERSIST_SEARCH_END,
                NUMA_NO_NODE);
        if (!alloc) return alloc;
        if (memblock_reserve(alloc, size)) {
            pr_err("info_keeper: memblock_reserve failed\n");
            return 0;
        }
        return alloc;
    #else
        unsigned long where;
        for (where = PERSIST_SEARCH_END - size;
             where >= PERSIST_SEARCH_START && where <= PERSIST_SEARCH_END - size;
             where -= PERSIST_SEARCH_JUMP) {
            if (reserve_bootmem(where, size, BOOTMEM_EXCLUSIVE))
                continue;
            else
                return where;
        }
        return 0;
    #endif
    }
    
    struct logbits *log_buf_alloc(char **new_logbuf)
    {
        char *buf;
        phys_addr_t alloc;
        unsigned long size = sizeof(struct logbits);
        unsigned long full_size = size;
        struct logbits *new_logbits;
    
        alloc = physmem_reserve(full_size);
        if (alloc) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "info_keeper: memory reserved @ 0x%08x\n", alloc);
            buf = phys_to_virt(alloc);
            if(buf){
                *new_logbuf = buf;
                new_logbits = (void*)buf;
                printk(KERN_INFO "info_keeper: memory virtual @ 0x%08x\n", buf);
                if (new_logbits->magic != PERSIST_MAGIC) {
                    printk(KERN_INFO "info_keeper: header invalid, " "cleared.\n");
                    memset(buf, 0, full_size);
                    memset(new_logbits, 0, sizeof(*new_logbits));
                    new_logbits->magic = PERSIST_MAGIC;
                } else {
                    printk(KERN_INFO "info_keeper: header valid; " "state=%d\n" "nb_reboot=%d\n", new_logbits->state, new_logbits->nb_reboot);
                }
                return new_logbits;
            }else{
                printk(KERN_ERR "info_keeper: failed to get phys to virt");
                buf = alloc_bootmem(full_size);
                *new_logbuf = buf;
                new_logbits = (struct logbits*)(buf);
                memset(buf, 0, full_size);
            }
        } else {
            /* replace the buffer */
            printk(KERN_ERR "info_keeper: failed to reserve bootmem " "area. disabled.\n");
            buf = alloc_bootmem(full_size);
            *new_logbuf = buf;
            new_logbits = (struct logbits*)(buf);
            memset(buf, 0, full_size);
        }
        return new_logbits;
    }
```

Upon execution, the `physmem_reserve` function is successful and returns a memory region. Then I get a physical to virtual memory mapping from `phys_to_virt`. Then, when I try to access the memory, I get this `Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address` error.

Here is a sample output :

```
[   42.489639] info_keeper: memory reserved @ 0x5dffffc0
[   42.494781] info_keeper: memory virtual @ 0x0dffffc0
[   42.499778] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 0dffffc0
```

Any idea on what is happening ?

Comment: Old post but maybe it'll help. I'm facing a similar issue on my side with an Rockchip based ARM64 board.
The root cause seems to be a mismatch between Device Tree used and hardware.
I didn't solved it yet, but working on it.

Comment: For me I've done it the other way arround. Now I reserve a small amount of memory at the end of the RAM with kernel arguments I send through the boot command in  U-Boot `setenv("bootargs", "memmap=1M$0x7FF00000 mem=2096128k`.
Then I ioremap the region `char* alloc = ioremap (0x8FF00000 /*2096128k + START@*/, 0x100000 /*1M*/);` and work in this region